# Proxy configuration scripts and BizTalk WCF-WebHttp adapter

Tags: wcf, proxy, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm trying to use a proxy configuration script ([Web Proxy Auto-Discovery (WPAD)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fze2ytx2(v=vs.110).aspx)) together with the WCF-WebHttp adapter. As it is not possible to configure the url to the script directly on the adapter properties dialog I defined a default proxy in BizTalks config file.

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">

  <proxy usesystemdefault="False" scriptLocation="http://<server>:9001/proxy.pac" />

</defaultProxy>
```

But it seems that the proxy is never configured.

I was thinking that maybe that setting "Do not use proxy" on the adapter causes the UseDefaultWebProxy property to be set to false? But it is not possible to set anything else since that requires that we set a uri directly to the proxy server.

Has anyone used proxy scripts together with BizTalk and WCF-WebHttp adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the WCF-WebHttp adapter for some reason sets the UseDefaultWebProxy to false. It works as expected when I added an endpoint behavior that just sets that property to true.

```
        var binding = endpoint.Binding as WebHttpBinding;

        if (binding != null)
        {
            binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        }
```